# Create an external URL hyperlink with JasperReports

Tags: jasper-reports

How do you include a hyperlink (URL) in a PDF that links to an external site?

Using a simple string like "http://www.stackoverflow.com", a link is automatically generated. But, how can I use a URL like `<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">Click here</a>`?

If I use this HTML string, Jaspers create a link but also shows the code.

Using JasperReports 4.0.4 and iReport 4.5.1.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

To make a textField a hyperlink to an external URL, you need to add the attribute `hyperlinkType="Reference"` to the element, and add a `<hyperlinkReferenceExpression>` tag within it. The reference expression is where you put the URL.

For example:

```
<textField hyperlinkType="Reference" hyperlinkTarget="Blank">
    <reportElement x="5" y="5" width="200" height="15"/>
    <textElement/>
    <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["Click Here!"]]></textFieldExpression>
    <hyperlinkReferenceExpression><![CDATA["http://www.google.com"]]></hyperlinkReferenceExpression>
</textField>
```

The `hyperlinkTarget` attribute behaves in the same way as the `target` attribute in HTML.

Note that only textFields, images, and charts can be hyperlinked in this way.

Comment: Reason this solution didn't work for me was ***hyperlinkTarget="Blank"***, specifically ***"Blank"***. Worked okay with **"Self"**, tho, thanks to this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/52560382/12322350) (thank you!!). Even though official documentations specifies "Blank" as a valid property.

https://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/tibco-jaspersoft-studio-user-guide/v60/anchors-bookmarks-and-hyperlinks

Answer (score 3):

For some reasons, the example given didn't work. I used [wayback machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20120622105137/http://jasperforge.org/uploads/publish/jasperreportswebsite/trunk/sample.reference/hyperlink/index.html) and found the following snippet that worked:

```
<textField hyperlinkType="Reference">
  <reportElement x="5" y="95" width="300" height="15"/>
  <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String">"  >> Click here to go to www.google.com"</textFieldExpression>
  <hyperlinkReferenceExpression>"http://www.google.com
</hyperlinkReferenceExpression>
    </textField>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a hyperlink **within** a regular text, set `markup` to `html` and use html tags:

```
<textField>
    <textElement markup="html"/>
    <textFieldExpression>
        <![CDATA["Text before hyperlink <font color='blue'><u><a href=\"http://www.stackoverflow.com\">Click here</a></u></font> Text after hyperlink"]]>
    </textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```