# JasperReports: How to add External url link in report

Tags: java, jasper-reports, tomcat6

I need a code to add external link link "www.google.com" in jasper report. I follow the answer of stackoverflow link [Create a url link with JasperReports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11254009/create-a-url-link-with-jasperreports) but it did not work. When i launch the jasper report in browser(PDF View)  the link is shown in browser, but when i click no event happen in browser.

Following is the textField code (from *JRXML*):

```xml
<textField hyperlinkType="Reference" hyperlinkTarget="Blank">
    <reportElement x="5" y="5" width="200" height="15"/>
    <textElement/>
    <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["GOOGLE"]]></textFieldExpression>
    <hyperlinkReferenceExpression><![CDATA["http://www.google.com"]]></hyperlinkReferenceExpression>
</textField>
```

Comment: Following is not being displayed :-) However why not just put a static label with the link?

Comment: Works fine for me (followed the exact same question) - Export to PDF, click, pass through the security manager and onto the web link...

Comment: @MadProgrammer, please explain more about the "pass through the security manager". how it works, the term is new for me.

Comment: When I click on the link I created (from within Adobe Acrobat Reader), it pops up a small "Security Window" dialogue saying "The Document is trying to connect to ...." etc... and asks if I want to "Allow", "Block" or "Cancel" (I can also remember the choice)

Comment: I also get the dialog box on jasper report launch but the dialog is "Open file with difeerent viewer." and when i click on dialog its save my pdf file into local disk.

Answer (score 4):

When I had the same issue, I changed Link Target from *Blank* to *Self* and it works.

[image: screenshot of hyperlink properties]

Comment: whohoo!  Thanks! Works on JR 6.17  JrPdfExporter. Thanks!