# to display a hyperlink in jasper report using java

Tags: java, jsp, jasper-reports

I want to populate a link on jasper report , on click it will call a struts2 action with 2 parameters. I have generated a jasper report using jasper reporting tool, now my requirement is to display a hyperlink in that report & on click of that link its will call to a struts2 action.
 Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11254009/create-a-url-link-with-jasperreports

Comment: on click of that link its no going to  the specified path . i tried this before also.